# Passing BSON to Silverlight client?

Tags: silverlight, mongodb

I am building a little app that has to communicate with a MongoDB database. Of course there is a web service in front of the DB and I am **not** trying to access the DB directly from silverlight. At first I thought to have this service return BSON objects in order to have the client manage them.

Is this even possible? It seems like I can't even add the BSON driver's dlls to the Silverlight app (they disappear from References immediately after closing the Add reference dialog, which seems to indicate they are not compatible with Silverlight).

Or maybe I got totally lost and misunderstood it all?? It's my first attempt with MongoDb...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to manipulate BSON objects on the client?

I'd say: let mongodb driver deal with BSON, then convert data to a more usable format (JSON / XML or similar) and pass it to silverlight client.

This is better because:

1. Client doesn't know about underlying database. What if BSON format got upgraded? You would have to recompile and deploy all clients.
2. Client doesn't know about underlying database. It communicates with the server using its own JSON (XML) based protocol. You might be able to even switch DB to MySQL and clients won't notice.

Comment: Yes, that's the route I've taken. My reasoning was that I will potentially have a lots of data, and I see this as a double conversion, one from the BSON format to an interchange format (say JSON), then from this format to the final, client-processable format. Just did not want to do things twice, once on the server and once on the client...

Comment: @Palantir: that's a micro-optimisation. I'm sure you have bigger things to worry about :-)

Comment: With the greatest of respect to @SergioTulentsev, this is a cop-out. The app I work on transfers data in small quantities over a large number of clients. We added a BSON serialisation option, and switched from string field names to integers with a shared lookup table. The new format is around 50% of the size of JSON data, (similar to Protocol Buffers), and it's 1/3rd faster to parse, too. It'll save us a significant amount on bandwidth costs in aggregate. We used a .NET server to iOS client, but you could try this lib for Silverlight: http://code.google.com/p/mongodb-silverlight-driver/. YMMV.